# Choosing a maximum randomly in the case of a tie?

Tags: python, list, max, tuples, min

From experiment I have relised that when in a case of a tie,
python picks based on order (e.g. the item that comes in first in a list)
Is there a way, where in the case of a tie i can choose an item randomly, so that it is not deterministic and based on order?

e.g.

```
l = [ ([1], 10) , ([2], 3), ([3], 9), ([4], 10)] 
max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

each run of this, could either return ([4], 10) or ([1], 10)
and not always ([1], 10)

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly (ie, tell `max` to do it randomly) but you can do a `max` followed by a `filter` followed by a `random.choice`.

Answer (score 6):

Shuffle the list before picking the maximum:

```
import random
random.shuffle(l)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could add a little randomness to the key value:

```
max(l, key=lambda x: x[1] + random.random())
```

Or more generally, in case your keys aren't only integers:

```
max(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], random.random()))
```

Comment: That could (in general) cause a non-maximum item to exceed a true maximum.

Comment: how could it cause a non-maximum item to exceed a true maximum? I have just ran multiple iterations, and in every iteration the maximum seems to be true

Comment: @user, .7 gets added to 2.5 and .1 gets added to 3, what will get returned as the max? It is ok with whole numbers but as chepner said in general not a good approach

Comment: @chepner I thought that was obvious, but thanks for pushing :-). I added a general variant now.

Comment: That's a good fix. It will work for *any* type, not just numbers.

Comment: Note that the second method is not perfectly uniform, There's a small chance two random values will be equal.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to find all the max's first then pick one randomly:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from random import choice

l = [([1], 10) , ([2], 3), ([3], 9), ([4], 10)] 

mx = max(l, key=itemgetter(1))

all_maxes = [ele for ele in l  if ele[1] == mx[1]]

print(choice(all_maxes))
```